# Паттерн "цепочка обязанностей"

Tags: delphi, шаблоны-проектирования

Как реализовать в delphi?

Comment: Это вы про ленивую загрузку ?

Answer (score 2):

Про сам паттерн можно почитать в книге [**Приемы объектно-ориентированного программирования**](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2457392/) или в этом [**референсе,**](http://codelib.ru/pattern/chain_of_responsibility/) который, собственно говоря, дублирует информацию из соответствующей книги.

---

*Из более-менее адекватных реализаций на `Delphi` понятнее всего выглядит следующая:*

```
unit Pattern;

interface

uses SysUtils;

type

  TPurchase = class
  public
    Number: integer;
    Amount: Double;
    Purpose: string;
    constructor Create(num: integer; am: Double; pur: string);
  end;

  IApprover = interface
  ['{3ACA3967-FFCF-48A1-AC45-9A9B98A8DD96}']
    procedure SetSuccessor(successor: IApprover);
    procedure ProcessRequest(purchase: TPurchase);
  end;

  TApprover = class(TInterfacedObject, IApprover)
  protected
    FSuccessor: IApprover;
  public
    procedure SetSuccessor(successor: IApprover);
    procedure ProcessRequest(purchase: TPurchase); virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TDirector = class(TApprover)
    procedure ProcessRequest(purchase: TPurchase); override;
  end;

  TVicePresident = class(TApprover)
    procedure ProcessRequest(purchase: TPurchase); override;
  end;

  TPresident = class(TApprover)
    procedure ProcessRequest(purchase: TPurchase); override;
  end;

implementation

{ TApprover }

procedure TApprover.SetSuccessor(successor: IApprover);
begin
  FSuccessor := successor;
end;

{ TDirector }

procedure TDirector.ProcessRequest(purchase: TPurchase);
begin
  if purchase.Amount < 10000.0 then
    WriteLn(Format('Director approved request # %d', [purchase.Number]))
  else if FSuccessor  nil then
    FSuccessor.ProcessRequest(purchase);
end;

{ TVicePresident }

procedure TVicePresident.ProcessRequest(purchase: TPurchase);
begin
  if purchase.Amount < 25000.0 then
    WriteLn(Format('VicePresident approved request # %d', [purchase.Number]))
  else if FSuccessor  nil then
    FSuccessor.ProcessRequest(purchase);
end;

{ TPresident }

procedure TPresident.ProcessRequest(purchase: TPurchase);
begin
  if purchase.Amount < 100000.0 then
    WriteLn(Format('President approved request # %d', [purchase.Number]))
  else
    WriteLn(Format('Request# %d requires an executive meeting!', [purchase.Number]))
end;

{ TPurchase }

constructor TPurchase.Create(num: integer; am: Double; pur: string);
begin
  Number := num;
  Amount := am;
  Purpose := pur;
end;

end.
```

---

```
program Behavioral.ChainOfResponsibility.Pattern;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Pattern in 'Pattern.pas';

var
  Director: IApprover;
  VicePresident: IApprover;
  President: IApprover;
  Purchase: TPurchase;

begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutDown := DebugHook <> 0;
  try
    Director := TDirector.Create;
    VicePresident := TVicePresident.Create;
    President := TPresident.Create;

    try
      Director.SetSuccessor(VicePresident);
      VicePresident.SetSuccessor(President);

      Purchase := TPurchase.Create(2034, 350.00, 'Supplies');
      Director.ProcessRequest(Purchase);

      Purchase.Free;
      Purchase := TPurchase.Create(2035, 32590.10, 'Project X');
      Director.ProcessRequest(Purchase);

      Purchase.Free;
      Purchase := TPurchase.Create(2036, 122100.00, 'Project Y');
      Director.ProcessRequest(Purchase);

      ReadLn;
    finally
      Purchase.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```